# How to redirect website from non www to www ( Windows +Wamp+Joomla)

Tags: joomla-2.5, .htaccess-configuration, seo, ssl, https

I have an issue here where I have already added line below into .htaccess file, AllowOverride all in httpd.conf file, enabled Use URL Rewriting from Joomla, but none of those work. Did I miss out anything or are there anything wrong with below line? I'm kind of out of idea now :((

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: if you put some random chars in this htaccess file does your site throw a 500 error? If not then you know that it isn't being looked at.  Also, did you try ^abc\.com with a backslash? It usually doesn't matter but may as well try it.

Comment: @jj9 while you wait for answers/feedback, please take the [tour] and consider editing your profile to introduce yourself to the community.

Comment: @jamesgarrett Nope, did not throw up any error as well. So it means it not even read .htaccess file?

Comment: @mickmackusa Noted will update accordingly.

Comment: apache config files are "last setting wins" so is it possible there's another AllowOverride directive that could apply to this later in the config after the "all" that changes it?

Comment: And one other suggestion: If you can edit the config file, change the log level to get more detail on rewrites. If your normal level is "info," for example, use "LogLevel info rewrite:trace6" and make a couple of requests, then change it back before the verbosity eats your disc.

Comment: Hi, @Arlen I'm sorry but I don't understand cuz I'm really new in Joomla. I just google around and seek for an answer and I end up with add the line to .htaccess file,AllowOverride all in httpd.conf file, enabled Use URL Rewriting from Joomla, but none of those work..

Comment: Redirecting to www and AllowOverride aren't Joomla things at all, they are webserver things, and they take effect long before Joomla even starts up; they're in place and active before Joomla arrives on scene. They're also specific to the apache webserver, so if you're running Joomla with a different server, none of that will help; you'd have to use config directives specific to your server.

Comment: But we are now using Windows server with wamp, are there any possibilities to do so?

Comment: Hi Petri! Are you sure you are still using the Apache Server? You mention WAMP in your question title - but actually it's uncertain if that's a correct usage of this acronym. You are also trying to redirect from non-www to www... which means this is an online site (???) -- Please clarify...

Comment: Hi FFrewin, we use WAMP as a substitute as WAMP contain everything in one(PHP, Apache and, etc.) and yes, is an online site.

Comment: Have you configured WAMP to use https? It doesnt work out the box. It requires config changes

Comment: Yes, the website currently uses https and no issue. Just I need to try to configure it to redirect from non-www to www. I've done all the required configuration but still when type abc.com in the browser it still does not redirect to https:// www.abc.com